# Merge multiple .dmp files to one.dmp file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dump, oracle9i

I use Oracle 9i under windows server 2003, I have multiple .dmp files and I want to merge them into one (one .dmp file), knowing that all the files have the same schema but different data.  how can I do to solve this problem

Comment: You can't do that. If they were created as separate files they must be imported as separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data and assuming that the dump files have the same structure but unique data you could simply import all your dump files in a temporary database schema and them import the schema as one single dump file.